# Monitoring mongrel with monit

Tags: web-server, monitoring, monit, mongrel

I wrote a monit.d file for mongrels which works in this version:

```
check process redmine with pidfile /home/redmine/service/redmine.pid
group webservice

start program = "/usr/bin/mongrel_rails start -p 41328 -e production -d --pid /home/redmine/service/redmine.pid --user redmine --group redmine -a 127.0.0.1 -c /home/redmine/app"
stop program  = "/usr/bin/mongrel_rails stop --pid /home/redmine/service/redmine.pid  -c /home/redmine/app && rm /home/redmine/service/redmine.pid > /dev/null 2>&1"

if cpu greater 50% for 2 cycles then alert
if cpu greater 80% for 3 cycles then restart


if totalmem greater 60.0 MB for 5 cycles then restart
if loadavg (5min) greater 4 for 8 cycles then restart

if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout


$ Checking monit control file syntax...
$ Control file syntax OK
```

I want to also monitor the http response, so I add this line at the end:

```
if failed port 41328 protocol http with timeout 10 seconds then restart
```

Now monit complains:

```
$ Checking monit control file syntax...
$ /etc/monit.d/redmine:16: Error: exceeded maximum number of program arguments 'http'
$ ERROR: CHECK MONIT CONFIG FILE SYNTAX
```

How do I correctly monitor the port?

*EDIT:* I found my mistake at last: I accidently did not put the closing quotes at the end of the "stop program" line above. I now corrected it in the question and also on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake at last: I accidently did not put the closing quotes at the end of the "stop program" line above. I now corrected it in the question and also on my server.

Now also the port line works without change:

```
if failed port 41328 protocol http with timeout 10 seconds then restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct instruction would be:

```
if failed port 41328 protocol http then restart
```

The `with timeout 10 seconds` applies when starting a program to create a failure after timeout.

Best regards,
João Miguel Neves

Comment: jneves thank you for your answer. In the end I could not confirm your information from the behaviour of monit. After I corrected my other error my original directive was accepted and also shows on the status page like this: "If failed localhost:41328 [HTTP via TCP] with timeout 10 seconds 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then restart else if passed 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then alert"